# JQuery Table Row Click Expand/Collapse

Tags: jquery, css

I have tried multiple solutions but none have worked for me yet. I have a table with some rows that can be considered section headers or keys and others that contain items under that header or key.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th colspan="2">Name</th><th colspan="2">Date</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr class="key"><td colspan="4">AAA</td></tr>
        <tr class="item"><td colspan="2">ANAME</td><td colspan="2">20200101</td></tr>
        <tr class="item"><td colspan="2">ANAME</td><td colspan="2">20200101</td></tr>
        <tr class="item"><td colspan="2">ANAME</td><td colspan="2">20200101</td></tr>
    <tr class="key"><td colspan="4">BBB</td></tr>
        <tr class="item"><td colspan="2">BNAME</td><td colspan="2">20200101</td></tr>
        <tr class="item"><td colspan="2">BNAME</td><td colspan="2">20200101</td></tr>
    <tr class="key"><td colspan="4">CCC</td></tr>
        <tr class="item"><td colspan="2">CNAME</td><td colspan="2">20200101</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When the page is loaded the rows with class `item` should be hidden using `CSS -> display:none`.
Ideally I should be able to click a header or `key` row and all `item` under that should expand and become visible. Additionally I want all other `item` not under the clicked `key` to be collapse if they were expanded.

My previous solutions used `slideToggle` and `toggleClass` but with either one or a combination of the two, I was not able to get the desired outcome.

My current version will only expand the next `item` in the table. There is currently nothing to tell others to close because I could not get any of my solutions to behave similar to what was desired.

```
$(".key").click(function(event) {
    $key = $(this);
    $content = $key.next();
    $content.slideToggle(0, function () {
        $key.text(function () {
            return;
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic idea using nextUntil() to get all the rows after it.

```js
$("table tbody").on("click", "tr.key", function () {
  var active = $(this)
  var trs = active.nextUntil(".key")
  trs.show();

  $("tr.item").not(trs).hide()

})
```

```css
.key {
  background-color: #CCC;
}
.item {
  display: none;
}

.item td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Name</th>
      <th colspan="2">Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="key">
      <td colspan="4">AAA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="item">
      <td colspan="2">ANAME</td>
      <td colspan="2">20200101</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="item">
      <td colspan="2">ANAME</td>
      <td colspan="2">20200101</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="item">
      <td colspan="2">ANAME</td>
      <td colspan="2">20200101</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="key">
      <td colspan="4">BBB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="item">
      <td colspan="2">BNAME</td>
      <td colspan="2">20200101</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="item">
      <td colspan="2">BNAME</td>
      <td colspan="2">20200101</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="key">
      <td colspan="4">CCC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="item">
      <td colspan="2">CNAME</td>
      <td colspan="2">20200101</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```